# Return Early Pattern in Dart/Flutter and splitting up methods

Tags: flutter, dart, early-return

I'm a long-time c# developer and now learning Dart/Flutter. In c#, I prefer the Return Early Pattern, for example:

```cs
private void myHandler()
{
    if (checkSomething())
    {
        doSomething();
        return;
    }

    if (checkSomethingElse())
    {
        doSomethingElse();
        return;
    }

    doRegularStuff();
}
```

Is that generally considered good practice in Dart as well? I created the following keyboard handler in Dart, inspired by various examples I found online. For formatting, I've used the `dart format` command line command. I find it really ugly to be honest:

```dart
  /// Handles key presses.
  KeyEventResult _keyPressed(FocusNode node, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event is! KeyDownEvent) return KeyEventResult.ignored;
    if (event.isBarcodeChar()) {
      _keyboardBuffer.write(event.character);
    } else if (event.isBackspaceKey() && _keyboardBuffer.isNotEmpty) {
      String shortenedBuffer =
          _keyboardBuffer.toString().substring(0, _keyboardBuffer.length - 1);
      _keyboardBuffer.clear();
      _keyboardBuffer.write(shortenedBuffer);
    } else if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
      _codeScanned(_keyboardBuffer.toString());
      _keyboardBuffer.clear();
    } else {
      return KeyEventResult.ignored;
    }
    return KeyEventResult.handled;
  }

  /// Handles scaned barcodes.
  void _codeScanned(String code) {
    // Handle some stuff and update the state of the application
  }
}
```

The code of the `_keyPressed` method doesn't really make clear, when it returns `handled` or `ignored`. It also looks really clumped together. I've also learned in c#, that all those `else if` statements have a bad smell. So would it be a good pracitce in Dart to use the Return Early Pattern as well?

Bonus question: Is it considered good practice in Dart to create single-use methods like my `void _codeScanned()` to improve readability? The method is only used from within the keyboard handler and nowhere else.

The official Dart coding guideline is rather unclear in this aspect (or I'm too stupid to find the right chapter). So thank you for your profound help in advance.

Comment: I think that no matter the coding language, if you have a method that needs to handle a complex set of logic, there is no way around how it would look. To make the code above more readable,I can advise you to refactor the if clauses that have more than one line inside of them to single use methods (as you stated). That way, you will get the clear and more readable code you referred to in your C# example. Since I am unfamiliar with the logic you have here, it also might be worthwhile to draw the different states and see what you can combine.

Comment: Why not? Normal code.  If you are worried about whether the code is bad, then I can tell you that the code is quite normal and logical. I am writing the same code and I didn’t know that it was called  `Return Early` pattern. I call it this way, it’s easier to complete the operation with a simple return than to fence the garden for the sake of the beauty of the code.

Comment: @tomerpacific There is not much more going on outside. The app is quite simple. I'm converting an existing knockout.js-based web solution to Flutter as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing bad in using Return Early patern. It's using widely, you could take a look on the [either_dart](https://pub.dev/documentation/either_dart/latest/) package, for example.

Regarding functions which are called only once, I prefer to use inline functions. So I have done a little refactoring of your code to make it more readable:

```
KeyEventResult _keyPressed(FocusNode node, KeyEvent event) {
  void _codeScanned(String code) {
    //
    _keyboardBuffer.clear();
  }

  bool canDoBackspace() =>
     event.isBackspaceKey() && _keyboardBuffer.isNotEmpty;

  bool isEnter() => event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter;

  void doBackspace() {
    String shortenedBuffer =
      _keyboardBuffer.toString().substring(0, _keyboardBuffer.length - 1);
    _keyboardBuffer.clear();
    _keyboardBuffer.write(shortenedBuffer);
  }

  if (event is! KeyDownEvent) {
    return KeyEventResult.ignored;
  }
  if (event.isBarcodeChar()) {
    _keyboardBuffer.write(event.character);
  } else if (canDoBackspace()) {
    doBackspace();
  } else if (isEnter()) {
    _codeScanned(_keyboardBuffer.toString());
  } else {
    return KeyEventResult.ignored;
  }
  return KeyEventResult.handled;     
}
```

P.S. Which IDE do you use? VS Code can do an autoformat when you save a file or run a project.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. I wasn't even aware that you can inline functions in Dart, I'm using VS Code. How can I set that up?

Comment: Pleasde go to File - Preferences - Settings, type "format" in the search line. Find options "Editor: Format on <paste/save/type>" and check them as you want